# Azure function - Breakpoint not hitting during debug

Tags: azure-functions

I have a QueueTrigger function app that process files when it find a file in Azure file share/ Blob. My Azure function local.settings.json is pointing to my Dev environment in Azure.

However, when i am debugging, the breakpoint is not hitting.

When I checked that, from .csproj , the setting are like

```
     <None Update = “local.settings.json”>
      <copyToOutPutDirectory>PreserveNewest</copyToOutPutDirectory>

     <copyTopublishDirectory> 
  Never </copyTopublishDirectory>
```

Is it due to this breakpoint is not hitting?

What settings needs to be changed to make sure it hits breakpoint during debugging, while pointing to Azure subscription?

Edit:

From Azure portal, function app configuration, I see configuration settings, environment-> development.

Should I change this settings to Debug? Will it point to my local.settings.json . I am really doubtful, but just checking for any clue.

Hope I have explained this correctly. Thanks

Comment: If you have a QueueTrigger, it means you're using storage queues, right? Are you adding a message to the queue to trigger the Function? If so, how?

Comment: Yes, it’s storage queue and Adding a message “hello world” manually in the queue. The sequence is, 1. Keep the file 2. Put breakpoint and start debug 3. Add message in queue. Then, I think my breakpoint should hit.

Comment: Is the connection string to the storage account correct? Is the Function executed but your breakpoint doesn't hit, or does the Function never trigger at all? You can see if it's being executed by having a look at the console window it opens.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're mixing a couple of things.

Running and debugging Functions **locally** ...

1. doesn't require any settings in the Azure Portal.
2. doesn't require a Functions App in your Azure environment.
3. does enable you to connect to anything your *local machine* has access to.

Running and debugging Functions **in Azure** ...

1. does require the correct settings in the Function App configuration.
2. does require a Functions App in your Azure environment.
3. does enable you to connect to anything your *Function App* has access to.
4. does require you to have Remote debugging set to **on**.
5. does require you to attach the debugger to the instance running in Azure.

[image: Remote debugging]

I'm assuming you're running and debugging Functions locally. Based on the information in your question, my best guess would be that you either have an instance of the Function running in the cloud that's picking the messages before the one running locally has a chance to do so, or the connection to the storage account isn't correct.